# Background Image Quality

Tags: android

Android Development help please.

Can somone tell me how I might increase the quality of background images in my app? I have been using Photoshop where the images look great, then I save for the web as a png...then add it to my app... Then on the phone the image looks a little blurred.

Whats the best way to increase my image quality?

Comment: I would make sure you're saving it at an adequate resolution.  I'm will to bet that "save for web" reduces the resolution to 72 dpi which may not be enough for an android handset.

Comment: @Chris - turn that into an answer, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make sure you're saving it at an adequate resolution. I'm will to bet that "save for web" reduces the resolution to 72 dpi which may not be enough for an android handset.  In photoshop, try bumping the resolution of the final png to something like 300 dpi and see if that makes a difference.  From there you can experiment with different resolutions to figure out what's the smallest value you can use and still have a crisp image.  Alternatively, you could just look for the documented resolution requirements.

Comment: Sorry, but the dpi is irrelevant for computer images. That's only going to matter if you're creating your images at a physical size (e.g. inches, millimeters). The dpi is then used as a calculation of how many pixels across each unit is (e.g. 3" image at 300dpi would be 900px wide). The only measurement you need to worry about is the exact pixel size. The likely problem is that the image is being scaled. If you're using an ImageView, try setting the ScaleType to CENTER.

Comment: @kcoppock, it's actually not irrelevant.  And what you're saying supports that, but I get what you're saying.  Ultimately, on a computer screen if the resolution is less than 72dpi, the image is going to look blurry.  So a 3" image at 300dpi can be scaled to 12.5" and still look clear.  Alternatively, you can do those calculations just on raw size alone, if you have a 900px wide screen, make the image 900px wide and you're good.  The trick is to make sure that you are getting at least 72dpi when the image is displayed otherwise it will look blurry regardless of anything else.

Comment: Again, only if you're making your measurement in inches. The 72 isn't important, most monitors are above 72, some are below (mine at work measures around 90) but the pixel size is all that matters for a computer display, unless you're specifically setting it to display at a physical dimension, in which case the image will be resampled to fit whatever dpi it's set to. If it's being viewed at 100%, it won't be resampled, but it will differ in physical size on the display.

Comment: Also, the 72 does come into play, say if you ARE trying to display an image at a fixed physical size. For example, let's say you're designing a business card at 3.5" x 2" and tell your software to display the image at actual size, it's going to use the de facto 72 dpi for its calculations. You'll have a displayed image taking 252 pixels in width, 144 pixels in height. If you take a ruler though, it's unlikely it will actually match the requested dimensions (3.5" x 2"), since the monitor dpi will vary from 72. Some software (Adobe Acrobat) lets you specify a dpi constant for your monitor.

Comment: So you have a point when you say at low dpi, a picture will be blurrier. It's not because of the dpi specified in the image, though, it's the actual amount of pixels per inch in the display. Say you have an original Droid at 854x480, and a Droid X also at 854x480. They both display the same number of pixels, but on the Droid, they are packed closer together, so the image appears sharper and clearer. The actual pixels of the image are the same, though.

Answer (score 1):

The apparent quality of your images may also depend in the type of device you are displaying the images on.  For example, if your image is saved as 72px x 72px in your image editor, then displayed with a size defined using 72 scaled pixels (sp) in android on a high pixel-density device, then the OS will stretch the image before display.  As such, the pixel density of the display device can affect the apparent image quality.

You can provide different resolution images for different pixel densities by using the hdpi, mdpi and ldpi folders for drawables.  See these links for more info:

- [Screens support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
- [Icon design](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html)